# Looking for a filter to modify the months

Tags: wordpress, date

Hi making a simple plugin that replaces the wrong russian month with the right ones.
But I can't find any filters that works.

I have tried these filters without success:

> add_filter('get_the_modified_date', 'russian-month');
>   add_filter('the_modified_date', 'russian-month');
>   add_filter('date_rewrite_rules', 'russian-month');

Comment: "replace the wrong russian month with the right ones" - can you please elaborate?

Comment: @Anand For some reason the month name that is outputted by php is in the wrong grammatic form. I can't speak russian so I don't know why but apparently, for example, "ктябрь" is outputted but the correct grammatic form is "октября" (notice the difference on the last letter)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just found out that you can use more functions as filters and not only the ones on http://codex.wordpress.org/Plugin_API/Filter_Reference#Date_and_Time_Filters

```
add_filter('get_the_date', 'russian-month');
```

did the trick for me :)